# Test case for angular services with put method included

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-services

I am learning about test cases with Jasmin and karma. I made an angular service that updates some records in the database. I have created test cases before, not an expert actually, but never for methods that put updates to the database.

This is my basic service with just one method:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WordsService {

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}

  associate(uuid: string, item):any {

    const url = 'update/associate' + uuid;
    this.http.put(url, item).subscribe(response => {
      return response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
}
```

And my test looks like this.

```
describe('WordsService', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let ordsService: WordsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [WordsService]
    });
  });

  httpMock = getTestBed().get(HttpClientTestingModule);
  sentimentTuningService = getTestBed().get(SentimentTuningService);

  it('should be updated', inject([SentimentTuningService], async(service: WordsService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();

    let mockWordId: string = "37945b85-f6a8-45fd-8864-f45f55df8c78";

    let mockData = {
      label: "My Cool label",
      word_config: "c836468f-1fb4-4339-b5a1-ebf72aa1c6a5",
      uuid: "37945b85-f6a8-45fd-8864-f45f55df8c78",
    };

     WordsService.associate(mockWordId, mockData)
      .subscribe(result => {
        expect(result.status).toBe(201);
      });

  }));

});
```

I don't know exactly how it is supposed to fake/mock the update in the database, and actually, I don't know if I am in the right way.

Obviously, I am getting problems with my test running.

[image]

Can you help me giving me an idea that how I need to test that service?

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests aren't generally meant to cover how units interact with the database, this is more the realm of e2e tests (protractor). Unit tests are more meant to cover "I am given this, I produce this or react this way". All of the IO should be faked at this level.

There are a number of great resource links readily available suggesting to use spies and mocks. If your service is calling the httpClient, it shouldn't test the action IO from the httpClient, but rather test how it reacts to provided I or O from the httpClient (if I said that in a way that makes sense).

A basic snipped (may need tweaking):

```
// inside of test
const spy = spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.callThrough();

... call method
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()

// or
const spy = spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.callThrough();

... call method with <values>
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<values>)
```

- [Codecraft](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/)
- [Alligator IO](https://alligator.io/angular/testing-with-spies/)
- [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#httpclienttestingmodule)